# 開き直ってしまえば気が楽だった. Is the ば working as a conditional here?

Tags: grammar

Not completely sure whether the ば is acting as a conditional or the grammar is something else because I can't quite understand the sentence.

Context is the guy was feeling a bit troubled before changing his mood again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Aすれば、Bだった means "I would have been B had I done A". In this case, A is 開き直ってしまう.

I can provide more explanation if you expound on what exactly you don't understand with the sentence.

Comment: It doesn't sound counterfactual in this case...